# Seeking guidance on implementing user interaction in Go and SDL programming

Tags: go, sdl

My program in Go initializes SDL, creates a window, and handles user events. It allows the user to select a start and end point and finds the shortest path between them, avoiding randomly generated obstacles. The selected points and squares are rendered on the screen using SDL, and the shortest path is drawn in green.The issue at hand is that I have developed functions for finding the shortest path between the start and end points, as well as for drawing the path on the screen. However, I am unsure how to implement them in a way that allows the user to select the points before calculating and displaying the path.

Since I'm new to programming in Go and using SDL, I've attempted to modify the main, handleEvents, and render functions, but I'm unsure how to do it correctly.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
    "sync"
    "time"

    "github.com/veandco/go-sdl2/sdl"
    "github.com/veandco/go-sdl2/ttf"
)

const (
    windowWidth       = 1000
    windowHeight      = 800
    fontPath          = "fonts/Terminal.ttf"
    fontSize          = 24
    numRandomSquares  = 100
    minSquareSize     = 10
    maxSquareSize     = 50
    maxSquarePosition = 1000
)

var (
    startPointColor = sdl.Color{R: 0, G: 255, B: 0, A: 255}
    endPointColor   = sdl.Color{R: 255, G: 0, B: 0, A: 255}
    pointSelected   bool
)

type Point struct {
    X     int32
    Y     int32
    Color sdl.Color
}

type Square struct {
    Rect  *sdl.Rect
    Color string
}

type Node struct {
    Point  *Point
    G      float64 // Koszt dotarcia do tego wierzchołka
    H      float64 // Heurystyka (szacowany koszt dojścia do punktu końcowego)
    F      float64 // Suma G i H
    Parent *Node   // Poprzedni wierzchołek w trasie
}

func initializeSDL() error {
    err := sdl.Init(sdl.INIT_EVERYTHING)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("błąd inicjalizacji SDL: %s", err)
    }
    return nil
}

func createWindow() (*sdl.Window, error) {
    window, err := sdl.CreateWindow("Find path", sdl.WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, sdl.WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, windowWidth, windowHeight, sdl.WINDOW_SHOWN)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("błąd tworzenia okna: %s", err)
    }
    return window, nil
}

func destroyWindow(window *sdl.Window, renderer *sdl.Renderer, font *ttf.Font) {
    if window != nil {
        window.Destroy()
    }

    if renderer != nil {
        renderer.Destroy()
    }

    if font != nil {
        font.Close()
    }

    ttf.Quit()
    sdl.Quit()
}

func handleEvents(running *bool, startPoint **Point, endPoint **Point, window *sdl.Window) {
    for event := sdl.PollEvent(); event != nil; event = sdl.PollEvent() {
        switch event := event.(type) {
        case *sdl.QuitEvent:
            *running = false
            return
        case *sdl.MouseButtonEvent:
            mouseEvent := event
            if mouseEvent.Type == sdl.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN && mouseEvent.Button == sdl.BUTTON_LEFT {
                if *startPoint == nil {
                    *startPoint = &Point{X: mouseEvent.X, Y: mouseEvent.Y, Color: startPointColor}
                } else if *endPoint == nil {
                    *endPoint = &Point{X: mouseEvent.X, Y: mouseEvent.Y, Color: endPointColor}
                }
            }
        case *sdl.WindowEvent:
            windowEvent := event
            if windowEvent.Event == sdl.WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE {
                *running = false
                window.Destroy()
                os.Exit(0)
                return
            }
        }
    }
}

func renderPoints(renderer *sdl.Renderer, points []*Point) {
    for _, point := range points {
        renderer.SetDrawColor(point.Color.R, point.Color.G, point.Color.B, point.Color.A)
        rect := &sdl.Rect{
            X: point.X - 5/2,
            Y: point.Y - 5/2,
            W: 10,
            H: 10,
        }
        renderer.FillRect(rect)
    }
}

func renderText(renderer *sdl.Renderer, font *ttf.Font, text string, textColor sdl.Color, x, y int32) error {
    textSurface, err := font.RenderUTF8Solid(text, textColor)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("błąd renderowania tekstu: %s", err)
    }
    defer textSurface.Free()

    textTexture, err := renderer.CreateTextureFromSurface(textSurface)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("błąd tworzenia tekstury: %s", err)
    }
    defer textTexture.Destroy()

    textWidth, textHeight := textSurface.W, textSurface.H
    textRect := &sdl.Rect{
        X: x,
        Y: y,
        W: textWidth,
        H: textHeight,
    }

    renderer.Copy(textTexture, nil, textRect)

    return nil
}

func render(renderer *sdl.Renderer, startPoint *Point, endPoint *Point, squares []*Square, font *ttf.Font, points []*Point) error {
    renderer.SetDrawColor(0, 0, 0, 255)
    renderer.Clear()

    renderPoints(renderer, points)

    if startPoint != nil {
        renderer.SetDrawColor(startPoint.Color.R, startPoint.Color.G, startPoint.Color.B, startPoint.Color.A)
        renderer.FillRect(&sdl.Rect{X: startPoint.X - 5/2, Y: startPoint.Y - 5/2, W: 10, H: 10})
    }

    if endPoint != nil {
        renderer.SetDrawColor(endPoint.Color.R, endPoint.Color.G, endPoint.Color.B, endPoint.Color.A)
        renderer.FillRect(&sdl.Rect{X: endPoint.X - 5/2, Y: endPoint.Y - 5/2, W: 10, H: 10})
    }

    renderer.SetDrawColor(255, 255, 255, 255)
    for _, square := range squares {
        renderer.FillRect(square.Rect)
    }

    textColor := sdl.Color{R: 255, G: 255, B: 255, A: 255}
    textY := int32(30)

    err := renderText(renderer, font, "Wybierz dwa punkty", textColor, (windowWidth-fontSize*10)/2, textY)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("błąd renderowania tekstu: %s", err)
    }

    if startPoint != nil {
        startText := "Start Point"
        startTextWidth, _, _ := font.SizeUTF8(startText)
        startTextX := startPoint.X - int32(startTextWidth)/2
        startTextY := startPoint.Y - 20

        startPointColor := sdl.Color{R: 0, G: 255, B: 0, A: 255} // Przykładowy kolor czerwony

        err := renderText(renderer, font, startText, startPointColor, startTextX, startTextY)
        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("błąd renderowania tekstu: %s", err)
        }
    }

    if endPoint != nil {
        endText := "End Point"
        endTextWidth, _, _ := font.SizeUTF8(endText)
        endTextX := endPoint.X - int32(endTextWidth)/2
        endTextY := endPoint.Y - 20

        endPointColor := sdl.Color{R: 255, G: 0, B: 0, A: 255} // Przykładowy kolor niebieski

        err := renderText(renderer, font, endText, endPointColor, endTextX, endTextY)
        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("błąd renderowania tekstu: %s", err)
        }
    }

    renderer.Present()
    return nil
}

func generateRandomSquares(numSquares int) []*Square {
    squares := make([]*Square, numSquares)
    for i := 0; i < numSquares; i++ {
        size := rand.Int31n(maxSquareSize-minSquareSize) + minSquareSize
        x := rand.Int31n(maxSquarePosition)
        y := rand.Int31n(maxSquarePosition)
        square := &Square{Rect: &sdl.Rect{X: x, Y: y, W: size, H: size}}
        squares[i] = square
    }
    return squares
}

func calculateDistance(point1, point2 *Point) float64 {
    xDiff := float64(point2.X - point1.X)
    yDiff := float64(point2.Y - point1.Y)
    return math.Sqrt(xDiff*xDiff + yDiff*yDiff)
}

func findShortestPath(startPoint, endPoint *Point, squares []*Square) []*Point {
    startNode := &Node{Point: startPoint}
    endNode := &Node{Point: endPoint}

    openList := []*Node{startNode}
    closedList := make(map[*Point]*Node)

    for len(openList) > 0 {
        currentNode := openList[0]
        currentIndex := 0

        for i, node := range openList {
            if node.F < currentNode.F {
                currentNode = node
                currentIndex = i
            }
        }

        openList = append(openList[:currentIndex], openList[currentIndex+1:]...)
        closedList[currentNode.Point] = currentNode

        if currentNode.Point == endNode.Point {
            path := []*Point{}
            current := currentNode
            for current != nil {
                path = append(path, current.Point)
                current = current.Parent
            }
            return path
        }

        neighbors := []*Point{}
        for _, square := range squares {
            rect := square.Rect
            if rect.W != rect.H && square.Color == "white" {
                continue // Omijaj białe kwadraty o różnych rozmiarach
            }
            if currentNode.Point.X >= rect.X && currentNode.Point.X <= rect.X+rect.W && currentNode.Point.Y >= rect.Y && currentNode.Point.Y <= rect.Y+rect.H {
                neighbors = append(neighbors, &Point{X: rect.X, Y: rect.Y + rect.H}) // Górny punkt
                neighbors = append(neighbors, &Point{X: rect.X + rect.W, Y: rect.Y}) // Prawy punkt
                neighbors = append(neighbors, &Point{X: rect.X, Y: rect.Y - 1})      // Dolny punkt
                neighbors = append(neighbors, &Point{X: rect.X - 1, Y: rect.Y})      // Lewy punkt
            }
        }

        for _, neighbor := range neighbors {
            if _, ok := closedList[neighbor]; ok {
                continue
            }

            g := currentNode.G + calculateDistance(currentNode.Point, neighbor)
            h := calculateDistance(neighbor, endNode.Point)
            f := g + h

            newNode := &Node{
                Point:  neighbor,
                G:      g,
                H:      h,
                F:      f,
                Parent: currentNode,
            }

            openList = append(openList, newNode)
        }
    }

    return nil
}

func drawPath(renderer *sdl.Renderer, path []*Point) {
    renderer.SetDrawColor(0, 255, 0, 255)
    renderer.SetDrawBlendMode(sdl.BLENDMODE_BLEND)
    renderer.SetDrawBlendMode(sdl.BLENDMODE_NONE)

    lineWidth := 5

    for i := 1; i < len(path); i++ {
        point1 := path[i-1]
        point2 := path[i]

        renderer.SetDrawColor(0, 255, 0, 255)
        renderer.SetDrawBlendMode(sdl.BLENDMODE_BLEND)
        renderer.SetDrawBlendMode(sdl.BLENDMODE_NONE)

        renderer.DrawLine(int32(point1.X), int32(point1.Y), int32(point2.X), int32(point2.Y))

        for w := -lineWidth / 2; w < lineWidth/2; w++ {
            renderer.DrawLine(int32(point1.X)+int32(w), int32(point1.Y), int32(point2.X)+int32(w), int32(point2.Y))
            renderer.DrawLine(int32(point1.X), int32(point1.Y)+int32(w), int32(point2.X), int32(point2.Y)+int32(w))
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    err := initializeSDL()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Błąd inicjalizacji SDL: %s\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    var renderer *sdl.Renderer
    var font *ttf.Font

    window, err := createWindow()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Błąd tworzenia okna: %s\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer destroyWindow(window, renderer, font)

    renderer, err = sdl.CreateRenderer(window, -1, sdl.RENDERER_ACCELERATED)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Błąd tworzenia renderera: %s\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer renderer.Destroy()

    err = ttf.Init()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Błąd inicjalizacji ttf: %s\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer ttf.Quit()

    font, err = ttf.OpenFont(fontPath, fontSize)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Błąd ładowania czcionki: %s\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer font.Close()

    startPoint := (*Point)(nil)
    endPoint := (*Point)(nil)

    pointsChannel := make(chan []*Point)
    running := true

    go func() {
        for running {
            points := []*Point{}
            if startPoint != nil {
                points = append(points, startPoint)
            }
            if endPoint != nil {
                points = append(points, endPoint)
            }
            pointsChannel <- points
            time.Sleep(10 * time.Millisecond)
        }
    }()

    squares := generateRandomSquares(numRandomSquares)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for running {
            handleEvents(&running, &startPoint, &endPoint, window)
            err := render(renderer, startPoint, endPoint, squares, font, <-pointsChannel)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Błąd renderowania: %s\n", err)
                running = false
            }
        }
    }()

    wg.Wait()

    close(pointsChannel)
}
```